# Via code force Swagger, Swashbuckle to use an existing type rather then generating a new one

Tags: c#, swagger, .net-6.0, openapi, swashbuckle

I am struggling to get Swagger to use the existing `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal` rather then creating its own version of it. I've used the googles, chatgpt, etc. all to no avail... the few bits of help I did find point to a possible solution via passing in parameters to the generator... but I know that I should be able to do it in code with something like this...

Here's what I have so far:

```cs
services.Configure<SwaggerGenOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SchemaFilter<ClaimsPrincipalFilter>();
    ...
}

public class ClaimsPrincipalFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    private const string existingNamespace = "System.Security.Claims";

    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Type != typeof(ClaimsPrincipal))
            return;

        schema.Reference = new OpenApiReference
        {
            Type = ReferenceType.Schema,
            Id = $"{nameof(ClaimsPrincipal)}, {existingNamespace}"
        };
    }
}
```

This results in the error:

> Resolver error at paths./v1/User.get.responses.200.content.text/json.schema.$ref
> Could not resolve reference: Could not resolve pointer: /components/schemas/ClaimsPrincipal, System.Security.Claims does not exist in document.

I just want to be able to pass my `User` as the original `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal`, without having to do any sort of mapping or worse yet the "JSON Serialize, Deserialize hack" on the other side. What am I missing?

**Edit:**
One variation that may or may not be progress here is to use `Id` a bit differently:

```
schema.Reference = new OpenApiReference
{
    Type = ReferenceType.Schema,
    Id = "System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal"
};
```

This gets rid of the error in Swagger UI, but now my endpoint of:

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ClaimsPrincipal), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public IActionResult GetCurrentUser() =>
    Ok(User);
```

Produces no result and the breakpoint on it doesn't ever get hit. Here is the response in Swagger UI hitting that endpoint:

```
content-length: 0 
date: Fri,02 Jun 2023 15:09:00 GMT 
server: Kestrel 
x-correlation-id: 0HMR3FD1SBL9O:00000009
```

Worse yet, this still creates a new model under the wrong namespace:

```
MyNamspace.Service.Client.v1.Models.ClaimsPrincipal
```

So that feel like a step backwards.

FYI, for now I am using this mapper on the other side to keep making progress:

```
public static ClaimsPrincipal AsPrincipal(this MyNamspace.Service.Client.v1.Models.ClaimsPrincipal user)
{
    if (user?.Claims == null || !user.Claims.Any())
        return null;

    var claims = user.Claims.Select(x => new Claim(x.Type, x.Value));

    return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
}
```

For anyone still following along this mess, there is a further complication as described here:
https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1713

So all of this is rather pointless as DTOs are required anyways.